# Re-assigning pandas col by dictionary has no effect on original DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge `pandas` `DataFrame` that looks like this (sample):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":{0:"There ARE NO ERRORS!!!", 1:"EVERYTHING is failing", 2:"There ARE NO ERRORS!!!"}, "col2":{0:"WE HAVE SOME ERRORS", 1:"EVERYTHING is failing", 2:"System shutdown!"}})
```

I have a function called `cleanMessage` that strips punctuation and returns lowercase string. For example, `cleanMessage("THERE may be some errors, I don't know!!")` would return `there may be some errors i dont know`.

I am trying to replace every message in `col1` with whatever `cleanMessage` returns for that particular message (basically cleaning these message columns up). `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` worked OK for me, but was a bit slow. I'm trying to basically map new values to the keys in the original `df`, something like this:

```
message_set = set(df["col1"])
message_dict = dict((original, cleanMessage(original)) for original in message_set)
df = df.replace("col1", message_dict)
```

So, the original `df` would like:

```
>>> df
    col1                      col2
0   "There ARE NO ERRORS"     "WE HAVE SOME ERRORS"
1   "EVERYTHING is failing"   "EVERYTHING is failing"
2   "There ARE NO ERRORS!!!"  "System shutdown!"
```

And the "after" `df` should look like:

```
>>> df
    col1                      col2
0   "there are no errors"     "WE HAVE SOME ERRORS"
1   "everything is failing"   "EVERYTHING is failing"
2   "there are no errors"     "System shutdown!"
```

Am I missing something with the `replace` portion of my code?

Edit:

For future viewers, here's the code I got to work:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].map(message_dict)
```

Comment: currently, df.replace() is looking for all instances of "col1" (the string, rather than the Series)

Comment: Why not just do `df["col1"] = [cleanMessage(s) for s in df["col1"]]`?

Comment: @JBr, so what should the syntax be, then, if I'm look to `replace` that column? `df = df.replace(df["col1"], message_dict)`?

Comment: piRSquared has the syntax below

Comment: He has some syntax that works, yes. But it's way slower than the method I put under "Edit" above, and doesn't use the dictionary replacement approach I outlined above

Answer (score 1):

`replace` works well with `regex` - consider putting the logic of `clean message()` into a nested `replace()`.

```
df["col2"] = df["col1"].replace(...).replace(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.lower().str.replace(r'([^a-z ])', '')

df
```

[image]